# Numeric list of directories & sub-directories in a selected directory

Tags: windows

Anybody able to advise the quickest way to find a numerical list of all directories & sub-directories within a chosen HDD directory?  Over the years I've amassed some 304Gb of music & I'd like to check that my master list in Excel is fully up to date!
Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by a numerical list?

Comment: rather than just say an alphabetic list of all the directories & sub-directories, a total of how many there are such that I can ascertain just how many albums I think I've got to double check against my master Excel list

Comment: Ah, you want to count the directories?

Comment: yes indeed; on the basis that each of my digitised albums is a sub-directory of larger directory, eg the directory structure I use is music/musician by alphabetical letter/musician name/album name

Comment: Ah. Then you probably want the second part of my answer :)

Comment: Many thanks David, will have a go with your batch file shortly

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I find the total number of subdirectories?

Use the following command:

```
dir /b /a:d /s 2> nul | find "" /v /c
```

If you want to traverse the directories and print the total number at each level use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
dir /b /a:d /s 2> nul | find "" /v /c > tmp && set /p count=<tmp && del tmp
echo top level total is !count! subdirectories
for /d /r %%d in (*) do (
  set count=0
  pushd "%%d"
  dir /b /a:d "%%d" /s 2> nul | find "" /v /c > tmp && set /p count=<tmp && del tmp
  if !count! neq 0 echo directory %%d contains !count! subdirectories
  popd
  )
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Dir - list files and folders - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [for /d - Loop through directory - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)